# How can I get real-time raw data using GoPro hero 5?

Tags: image, opencv, usb, real-time, gopro

I want to use camera for development.
Camera's model is GoPro hero 5.

But I can't find the way to get image data using GoPro.

Everyone use livestreaming using Wifi.

I want to get real-time raw image data using USB

How can I get the data?

Thanks

---

Connect USB to handle image in real-time
 -> Gopro's USB is only to charge

The only method offered by Gopro is the RTSP connection via the WIFI connection

Comment: Maybe try GoPro Tech Support?

Comment: yes. but nothing to solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you mean raw data? You could use HDMI or the MTP mount point of the HERO5 to get images

Comment: raw image data like mat to use image processing. I already success by using libvlc and I get the real-time image data.